# div's position placed next to FORM

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with `div` which I want to place next to the `form` with some `input` tag. When I use `display: inline-block` in both, `div` position goes a little lower than `form`'s position.

I really don't know why and how to resolve this problem. I tried to find the answer on the internet, but failed.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <form class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
  <div class="row">
    second column
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
input {
  display: block;
}

.row {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 48%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/saren86/e9jt8xyk/1/

Answer (score 0):

that behave is always weird but can be solved with `overflow: hidden;`

```css
input {
  display: block;
}

.row {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 48%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
  <div class="row">
    second column
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to use CSS3, the [flex layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) would be another option.

Simply set it on the body:

```css
body {
  display:flex;
}

input {
  display: block;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 48%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
  <div class="row">
    second column
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add float: left; to your .row class and you have it fixed.

```
.row {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 48%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dd5kku0k/

Comment: Ok, It works. However, if I want to center both - div and form, it will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a vertical-align:top; to .row selector;

```css
input {
  display: block;
}

.row {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 48%;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
  <div class="row">
    second column
  </div>
</body>
```